# Graphical interface (UI) wont load on ubuntu 12.04 after install

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon, gui

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 in virtual box. I cannot get the graphical interface to load only the terminal. The terminal comes up and i login but it stays on the terminal. I have tried the startx command and that dosent work. I also am told on boot thhat my system is running in low graphics mode. iIs this because i havent got the correct drivers. I have the ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics. Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh and clean installation, basic drivers should be available in order to install the new ones...

Here's a little help if you want to try the installation in the terminal :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Think about trying something like...

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

... first, but I don't really think it'll be productive.

Comment: I tried the command and it restarts but went back to the terminal

Comment: Try installing your graphic cards driver from the link I gave you earlier. The error you get at boot and the X server failures are probably linked. Could you give use a bit of your /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log file (edit your question) ?

Comment: i typed in /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log and it says permission denied

Comment: Only root can read this file. Use sudoers privileges to read it : `sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log` (or use another file reader)

Comment: Ijust got a bunch of words

Comment: You should try to install your graphic driver (c.f. the link in my answer).